# Windows stack and heap address ranges

Tags: winapi, memory, process, heap-memory, stack-memory

Working with Linux until now where stack addresses are very high and heap addresses are pretty low (as seen by printing heap and stack addresses using a C program), I have a problem with the Win32 process memory layout. MWSDN is saying that that stack addresses are higher than heap addresses, but from what I saw in practice, stack addresses are lower than heap addresses. So I am confused. Someone please explain.

Comment: Where in MSDN does it say that?

Answer (score 5):

Hm, `stack addresses are higher than heap addresses` - this is simply not true. Both stack and heap can reside anywhere in the address space of the process on Windows.

If you start a lot of threads, make huge heap allocations and load hundreds of dlls, you will find that all these objects are evenly spread around the address space.

[image]

This picture shows the structure of virtual allocations in a typical 32-bit process on Windows. Green shows free areas, blue that something is allocated. Activity is mostly taking place in the beginning of the address space but in other address ranges it is present also.

Comment: You can notice that all stack addresses on all of your threads are
at the low part of the address space, while heap allocations are in the higher addresses. I want to know if this is usual for Windows. If not, where does it say it and give more detail?

Comment: looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms836325.aspx you can tell heap is higher, but it is not.

Comment: I see. They give examples of memory layouts for simple processes. Yes, if you will load 2-3 dlls and start one thread, 99% chance that you will have layout, similar to these examples (by the way on Win7 it may easily differ from XP). But in a big server process that hosts hundreds of threads, you can have any layout.

Comment: That MSDN article only applies to: Microsoft® Windows® CE .NET, Microsoft Windows CE 3.0, Pocket PC 2002.

Comment: Maybe. I wrote my comments based on my own experience with Windows of both server and client versions. I know how these systems work.

Comment: Can I know which software the picture is captured from?

Comment: This is my own application that I wrote long time ago. I doubt you can see similar picture anywhere else. This is overview of the 32-bit application virtual address space. It gives an idea of how address space is occupied and how it is fragmented.

Comment: Thanks, I see. Yes, there is a similar function in Sysinternals vmmap.