# memory layout of stack and heap in user space

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, memory, operating-system

I'm recently studying the OS, and here is a picture online showing the memory layout of user space and kernel space, and the layout of stack, heap and so on.
In this figure I see that the stack is at the highest memory address in user space, higher than the heap, data segment and so on.

[image]

In order to check that, I used the memory watcher window in vs2012 under debug view, here's my code:

```
int a = 3;

int main()
{
    int b = 5;  
    int *p = new int[100];  
    delete [] p;
    return 0;
}
```

And I checked the memory address of `a(data segment),b(stack variable) and p(heap)`, but I found the **address of b is the lowest** among the three, so why is the result different from the picture above?
[image]

Comment: +1 for concise and clear question.

Comment: I suppose a is data segment and b is stack?

Comment: @Lashane I made a mistake, sorry for that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11925397/windows-stack-and-heap-address-ranges looks like this was asked before already. Since stack size is not "unlimited", it does not need to reside anywhere in particular. You are not limited to one stack anyway. Your picture is a simplification.

Answer (score 3):

That image looks like how Linux lays out the virtual address space, not Microsoft Windows.

Answer (score 2):

I have a memory map for a program in win32 which may help, it outlines the mapping for systems not using the `/3gb` switch:

[image: Win32 memory mapping]

As you can see win32 uses a slightly different memory mapping than linux (as pointed out in the other question) which the diagram you posted looks like.  I realise this memory diagram is old, however the same base tenets mostly apply in windows.

Let me know if you need more info though and I will try and rustle something up:)